# Database Connection String error

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, database-connection

Currently I am running MVC project using Oracle as my database.

When my solution runs, it throws the exception:

> 'entitycommandexecutionexception'.

I thought my webconfig file has some issues, so I looked in my webconfig.  When I tried to save it, my file was saved with the an error message

> "The 'data source' keyword is not supported".

My webconfig connectionstring is as follow:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="bob" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.bob.csdl|res://*/Entities.bob.ssdl|res://*/Entities.bob.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=localhost/XE;PASSWORD=bobsamuel;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=bobsamuel&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what kind of extension has your webconfig?? .. .xml?

Comment: yes my webconfig file extension is .xml

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is wrong. Pay attention on "**providerName**" part. Your's currently set to "System.Data.EntityClient" but it should be "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" - if you are using official Oracle driver.

Comment: I am using Entity framework that's why i have used providerName as 'System.Data.EntityClient'

Comment: Like i said. That is wrong. That one is for SQL Server, not Oracle. Good luck.